# How to connect HTML WebSocket to C++ Socket

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, websocket

I have an app where I am trying to connect to a C++ server which opens up a socket.

// Client side

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://<<IP:PORT>>');
```

In the server side, it is opening up a socket using

```
int sockfd = socket(domain, type, protocol)
```

(ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/)

Not aware of the c++ server implementation.

I was told that the server would start a WebSocket server to which my HTML app can connect.

But, the connection is not happening. I feel that the **WebSocket** on the client side is not same as **socket** on the server side and hence the connection is not establishing.

Please, someone, suggest what is wrong and how to make it right.

P.S. Please don't mind if it is a dumb question.

Comment: Try something specifically labeled as Websocket maybe? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371188/A-Cplusplus-Websocket-server-for-realtime-interact

Comment: socket != WebSocket

Comment: Whoever told you that a plain socket would magically turn into a WebSocket, is wrong.

Comment: @gre_gor what is the way to establish the connection, please suggest.I think the server should open up a WebSocket only then the WebSocket client can connect, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since the server guys are not ready to change their implementation of the plain socket, as a workaround I created a C++ client which connects to the server using the plain socket. Then I am creating a WebSocket Server using NodeJs which executes the C++ client as a child process to get the data. So, my WebSocket client is now able to get the data from the main server through the NodeJs WebSocket interface server.

Cons:

1. A dependency of the C++ client.
2. Latency (*since network speed is not a factor now, it works*).

Comment: Have you asked how the server guys intended for the socket to be used instead?

Comment: Yes, @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have asked them but they not fond of answering questions, so I followed the workaround as I was the one who was in need :)

Comment: The reason I ask is that they must have created it for _something_, and you may be better off using the data for its intended purposes, otherwise switching to something else entirely. Though your interface workaround does sound reasonable if this is what you have to do.